# Assigning a property to its self error in XCode 14.3

Tags: xcode, assign, xcode14.3

So I have been looking on here for some help with Xcode not allowing me to assign an property to itself. However, everything that I have found hasn't help me with the issue. So I thought maybe I'd ask directly. I am trying to assign self.recipeCategory to recipeCategory in the code below. Also Im new to swift so most likely its probably something super simple but for the life of me can't figure ou what to do. Thanks for the help.[Xcode code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzmOG.jpg)

self.recipeCategory = recipeCategory

Comment: Check your parameter name again. It is not "recipeCategory", it is "_recipeCategory".